# WPF DataGrid - How do I use cell and row validation with DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I use cell and row validation with DataGridTemplateColumn?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataType}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding DataType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static app:ApplicationConfiguration.DataTypes}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Some more context... what exactly do you want to do ? e.g. With the WPF Validation model (see IDataErrorInfo) + Data Binding , you can move your validation to a ViewModel class. The grid can remain blissfully unaware.

Comment: My model implement IDataErrorInfo, so I just want to trigger cell and row level validation.

Comment: A little more background. For text columns everything is working great. But for template or combobox columns I can't get the row-level validation to update when the value changes.

Comment: Nope. In the end I gave up on using editable data grids. Now I use ItemsControl unless the grid is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a guess, but it looks like you want to prevent certain items from being selected.  The easiest way would be to remove them from the list, but you could do it using validation as follows.

If the selected item is invalid, throw an exception in the Setter in the ViewModel:

```
public object DataType
{
    get { return dataType; }
    set
    {
        if(valueNotAllowed(value))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} is not a valid selection", value.ToString());
        dataType = value;
    }
}
```

Then set the binding for SelectedItem to ValidateOnExceptions (note that in your question, you specified *ValidatesOnErrors* for the *ItemsSource* binding - wrong property on the wrong binding):

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataType, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static app:ApplicationConfiguration.DataTypes}}"/>
```